# Store in IEnumerable property by using group by

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I want to create json object to represent job and list of users who has same job title and store it JobUsersList object

```cs
public class JobUsersList
{
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int JobID { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is to store `IEnumerable<User>`. I don't know what is the problem.

```cs
from user in userTB
join job in JobTB on userTB.JobID equals job.ID
group people by job into k
select new JobUsersList
{ 
     JobUsersList = k.key, 
     Users = ??
}
```

Comment: The above classes don't compile.  Can you edit them so that they do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing `group people` to `group use` it'll be easy: `k` will `IEnumerable<user>`. You probably want to call `ToList` on it, to avoid multiple enumerations.

```
from user in userTB
join job in JobTB on userTB.JobID equals job.ID
group user by job into k
select new JobUsersList
{ 
     JobUsersList = k.key, 
     Users = k.ToList()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax issues in your `join` statement, and you have to do the `join` before the `group`:

```
from u in userTB
group u by u.JobID into g
join j in jobTB on g.Key equals j.Id
select new JobUsersList
    {
        JobName = j.JobName,
        Users = g.ToList()
    }
```